# How correctly send data from forms to my URL?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post

How to read data from this forms and send it to my custom URL?

```
          <div className='contact-form-group'>
            <InputGroup size="small">
              <input type="text"
                     placeholder={'Enter Your Name'}/>
            </InputGroup>
          </div>
        <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
          <div className="contact-search-icon-container">
            submit
          </div>
        </InputGroupAddon>
```

my_url works like an echo: what you sent, you will receive in text form

```
handleSubmit = (event) => {

    event.preventDefault()
    const form = event.target
    const data = new FormData(form)

    for (let name of data.keys()) {
      const input = form.elements[name]
    }
    const proxyUrl = 'https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/'
    const url = 'my_url'
    fetch(proxyUrl + url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: data,
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },

    }).then(function (response) {
      //handle success
      console.log(response)
    })
      .catch(() => console.log('Can’t access ' + url + ' response. Blocked by browser?'))
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to pass `event.target` to `FormData` I think.

Here's a simple solution that shows how to handle files as well as text:

```js
import React from "react";

class Upload extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      image: ""
    };
  }

  handleFileChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.files[0]
    });
  };

  handleTextChange = e => {
    this.setState({
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  handleSubmit = async e => {
    e.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    for (let name in this.state) {
      formData.append(name, this.state[name]);
    }

    await fetch("/api/upload", {
      method: "POST",
      body: formData
    });

    alert("done");
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input name="image" type="file" onChange={this.handleFileChange} />
        <input name="name" type="text" onChange={this.handleTextChange} />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

export default Upload;
```

Comment: Thank you! But what is ' e.target.files[0]'? And how can I change handleFileChange  for sending just text instead of files?

Comment: @AlinaHomyakova you got it right. it's files. `files[0]` means first file just like an array. if you want to send just `text`, then do `e.target.value`. i've updated the code so you can check the function `handleTextChange`. if the solution is correct then you can mark it as an answer by ticking the checkbox :)